# Checking for Not Listening Ports from Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I am writing a batch file to automate certain redundant tasks. In the process, I need to find a port that is not listening so I can use it to install some services.

The current test code I have is:

```
@echo OFF
:getPort
Set /P oPort=Enter an open port (not listening) (eg: 9335)
echo %oPort%
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('netstat -an |find /i "%oPort%"') do (
    call set concat=%%concat%%%%a
    )
echo %concat%
IF [%concat%] != [] 
echo %oPort% is already in use.
GOTO getPort
```

It throws error `| was unexpected at this time.`

What I am trying to do in the code is:

1. Get a port number from user
2. Run the command for example: `netstat -an | find /i 9225` and store the output value in a variable
3. If the variable is NOT empty, it means the port is listening and so I need to prompt the user for another port.

Any guidance, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
netstat -an | findstr /r /c:"^  [TU][CD]P  *[^ ]*:%oPort% " >nul && goto :getPort
```

There is no need for the `for` command. Just test if the value can be found. If it can be found ask for another port.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I made it as netstat -an | findstr /r /c:"^  [TU][CD]P  *[^ ]*:%oPort% " >nul && echo Port is already in use && goto :getPort

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a for-loop to extract the output, I would suggest redirecting it into a file and going of that.

```
@echo OFF
:getPort
Set /P oPort=Enter an open port (not listening) (eg: 9335)
echo %oPort%
netstat -an |find /i "%oPort%"' > temp.tmp
set /p concat=<temp.tmp
del temp.tmp
echo %concat%
IF "%concat%" NEQ "" (
  echo %oPort% is already in use.
  GOTO getPort
)
echo %oPort% is not in use.
REM Not sure if you want to exit or continue
goto getport
```

Which should work.